# Aprender asp.net sem dominar c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

dúvida básica. Quero começar a programar para web com asp.net mvc, porém sei muito, muito pouco c#, apenas o básico da linguagem. Seria um mau negócio começar com asp.net e ir pegando a linguagem c# conforme for avançando o asp.net ? Se não, qual a parte principal do c# que devo focar antes de ir para o asp.net ?

Comment: Sua pergunta provavelmente vai ser fechada por ser principalmente baseada em opiniões pessoais, e não em fatos, e não é essa a ideia deste site. Além disso, independente da opinião de cada um, no final apenas você é que pode decidir isso, pois o caminho que você vai seguir, apenas você mesmo poderá trilhar.

Comment: No final o que importa é o seguinte: siga o seu coração, aprenda aquilo que você quiser aprender e quando quiser aprender, mas não tente abraçar o mundo. Eu poderia te dizer para focar no C#, ou focar no ASP.Net, ou levar os dois juntos, ou fazer alguma outra coisa. Nada disso importaria, pois seriam apenas opiniões aleatórias de alguém que não te conhece, pois no final a única pessoa que pode saber o que é melhor para você é você mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Seria um mau negócio começar com asp.net e ir pegando a linguagem c# conforme for avançando o asp.net?

Não, desde que você procure adensar conhecimento no C# conforme for estudando. Ou seja, se aparece uma construção no código que você não entende muito bem, procurar saber o porquê de ela ser usada e em que outros casos ela pode ou não ser usada.

## Se não, qual a parte principal do c# que devo focar antes de ir para o asp.net?

São algumas partes, na verdade:

- Disciplina de Tipos: C# é uma linguagem de tipagem forte. Evite usar tipos dinâmicos no começo. Deixe eles para quando a parte de tipos estiver dominada;
- Tratamento de Exceções: exceções são problemas sérios que precisam de tratamento especial no código. Evite ignorá-las ou criar mecanismos para abafá-las. Procure saber sempre o que cada uma significa e o que fazer no caso de elas aparecerem;
- Níveis de Proteção: são vários, cada um tem uma função bem específica. Procure se concentrar inicialmente em três:

  - `public`
  - `private`
  - `protected`
- Interfaces e Genéricos: A meu ver são o segundo grande diferencial da linguagem: a capacidade de definir classes que não conhecem exatamente um determinado tipo e o esquema de contratos, que garante segurança de código;
- *Reflection*: simplesmente o recurso mais poderoso da linguagem, a capacidade de ler metadados de classes e construções complexas;
- Extensibilidade: Meu favorito: a capacidade de estender uma classe sem conhecer o código dela.